Is it possible to get horizontal speed from a U-BLOX chip GPS?
While playing around with my UBX-M10 GPS chip, I realized than the speed given in the NMEA sentences is varying while doing small vertical movements.
So I guess it is a speed on trajectory rather than a speed over ground. And the reactivity of the speed seems to show that is that calculated using Doppler effect rather than interpolating between 2 points.
I need to calculate horizontal speed only. Is the only way to do this by interpolating between 2 GPS points ? Can the chip be configured to output a ground speed only ?
Thank you for the help

What about just calculating it? In any case ublox documents the commands, you may need to parse the list of command, to see if there is something useful dor you

Calculating it by interpolating between 2 points is far less accurate and fast-changing than the measurement given using Doppler effect, that's why I was interested in this. Thank you

Read the documentation, and check if you can have different output, or each inertial sensor (but it depends on the uBlox chip). Or if you think (I didn't check documentation) that it gives object speed, and you have vertical speed, with maths you should be able to calculate the ground speed. (it I remember correctly maths)

Thank you. This is one solution indeed, however I don't know if this Doppler-effect precision has the same accuracy in the horizontal plane than in the vertical one. Hard to know that. But I'll try.
